# XGBRegressor much slower than GradientBoostingRegressor

Tags: scikit-learn, xgboost

I am new to `xgboost` and am trying to learn how to use it by comparing it to the traditional `gbm`. However, I noticed that `xgboost` is much much slower than `gbm`. The example is:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold, GridSearchCV
from sklearn.ensemble import GradientBoostingRegressor
from xgboost import XGBRegressor
from sklearn.datasets import load_boston
import time

boston = load_boston()
X = boston.data
y = boston.target

kf = KFold(n_splits = 5)
cv_params = {'cv': kf, 'scoring': 'r2', 'n_jobs': 4, 'verbose': 1}

gbm = GradientBoostingRegressor()
xgb = XGBRegressor()

grid = {'n_estimators': [100, 300, 500], 'max_depth': [3, 5]}

timer = time.time()
gbm_cv = GridSearchCV(gbm, param_grid = grid, **cv_params).fit(X, y)
print('GBM time: ', time.time() - timer)

timer = time.time()
xgb_cv = GridSearchCV(xgb, param_grid = grid, **cv_params).fit(X, y)
print('XGB time: ', time.time() - timer)
```

On a Macbook Pro with 8 cores, the output is:

```
Fitting 5 folds for each of 6 candidates, totalling 30 fits
[Parallel(n_jobs=4)]: Done  30 out of  30 | elapsed:    1.9s finished
GBM time:  2.262791872024536
Fitting 5 folds for each of 6 candidates, totalling 30 fits
[Parallel(n_jobs=4)]: Done  30 out of  30 | elapsed:   16.4s finished
XGB time:  17.902266025543213
```

I thought xgboost should be much faster so I must be doing something wrong. Can someone help to point out what I am doing incorrectly?

Comment: This is what I got running your code exactly: `GBM time: 2.1901206970214844
XGB time:  2.5632455348968506`.

Answer (score 2):

This is the output when running on my machine, without setting `n_jobs` parameter in `cv_params`

```
Fitting 5 folds for each of 6 candidates, totalling 30 fits
[Parallel(n_jobs=1)]: Done  30 out of  30 | elapsed:    4.1s finished
('GBM time: ', 4.248916864395142)
Fitting 5 folds for each of 6 candidates, totalling 30 fits
('XGB time: ', 2.934467077255249)
[Parallel(n_jobs=1)]: Done  30 out of  30 | elapsed:    2.9s finished
```

When `n_jobs` is set to 4, the output is **2.5s** for GBM, but takes a very long time for XGB.

So maybe this is a problem with n_jobs! Maybe XGBoost library is not well configured to run n_jobs with GridSearchCV.

Comment: I believe it may be `nthreads` in XGBoost Library, not n_jobs in at least some versions of XGBoost which cause this issue. I've definitely encountered it before.

Comment: Yeah just dug this up: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46310578/parallel-threading-with-xgboost