# Parallel threading with xgboost?

Tags: python, machine-learning, xgboost

According to its documentation, xgboost has an n_jobs parameter. However, when I attempt to set n_jobs, I get this error:

```
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'n_jobs'
```

Same issue for some other parameters like random_state. I assumed this might be an update issue, but it seems I have the latest version (0.6a2, installed with pip).

There isn't much needed for me to reproduce the error:

```
from xgboost import XGBClassifier 
estimator_xGBM = XGBClassifier(max_depth = 5, learning_rate = 0.05, n_estimators = 400, n_jobs = -1).fit(x_train)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Could you add a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example?

Comment: Added. That's all I need to get the error

Comment: I reproduced the issue, so it's not something weird with your install. This seems likely to be a bug in `xgboost`, though I couldn't figure out how this is happening (n_jobs is an explicit kwarg of XGBClassifier). Try opening an issue on [Github](https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/issues)?

Comment: Submitted, thanks for the help

Comment: How have you checked the version? And are you running the code in the same environment?

Answer (score 13):

I installed xgboost yesterday (25.09.2017):

If you install with pip or conda, the xgboost version does not support the n_jobs parameter; only the nthreads parameter.

If you build xgboost from github repository, you can use n_jobs though.

> Update: `n_jobs` is the number of parallel threads used to run xgboost. (replaces nthread) for all algorithms like XGBClassifier, XGBRanker, XGBRegressor etc.

Reference - [here](https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/python/python_api.html)

Comment: As for 2018-01-18, `n_jobs` is there when installed with `pip` (`xgboost` v0.7).

Answer (score 5):

`nthread` is same with `n_jobs` but `n_jobs` is prefered for now.
maybe you can try `nthread` instead.

> nthread : int
>           Number of parallel threads used to run xgboost.  (Deprecated, please use n_jobs)
>
> n_jobs : int
>           Number of parallel threads used to run xgboost.  (replaces nthread)

[https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/blob/master/python-package/xgboost/sklearn.py#L71-L74](https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/blob/34dc9155abb81620f745b31bc096c5b4c74faf1e/python-package/xgboost/sklearn.py#L71-L74)

Answer (score 0):

Use this for n_jobs value for your machine

```
import multiprocessing
n_jobs = multiprocessing.cpu_count()-1
print(n_jobs)
```